# How to validate input against a randomly generated set of letters. Also, how to institute a rounds system

Tags: java, loops, validation

I'm working on an assignment (very much a beginners assignment)and am looking for some guidance as opposed to the code necessarily although obviously code is extremely helpful.

The assignment is essentially a version of Boggle with preset words (i.e. you're given random letters, you need to make a word, word must come from a short preset list or else you get zero). I have no idea where to start when validating the inputted word to ensure it only uses the randomly generated letters with no duplicates unless there are multiples of the same letter in the set. Here's the code for the random letter generator

Random r = new Random();
char[] real = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};

```
    for(int i=0; i < letters.length; i++) {
      letters[i] = real[r.nextInt(26)];
    }
```

The game also has a rounds system predicated on the user asking for another round at the completion of the first one. What kind of loop should I use for this. Am extremely used to for loops so that's what I went for but I'm feeling I'm probably wrong here. The rounds are identical so obviously I'd just like to loop over the pre-existing code. This is how I've written the round code so far, want to know what I should be insitituting now before going to deep into a mistake

```
         letters= Instantiable.getLetters(); //Retrieving encryption
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your random letters will be displayed" );
     System.out.println(random);



     //Input
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "please enter a word" );
     1Answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Player 1, your answer");
        if (p1Answer.matches("^[a-zA-Z]*$")) {
            System.out.println("Player 1's answer is :" + p1Answer);
             }
             else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your answer contains invalid characters.NO SOUP FOR YOU!" );
                }


     2Answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Player 2, your answer");
        if (p2Answer.matches("^[a-zA-Z]*$")) {
            System.out.println("Player 2's answer is :" + p2Answer);
             }
             else {
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your answer contains invalid characters.NO SOUP FOR YOU!" );
                }
     



}
```

}

I'm assuming I'm making a mistake by not slapping this into a do while loop, but honestly extremely unsure because I've mostly been coasting using for loops and thus, at this stage am extremely worried that if I choose the wrong loop at the outset I'll be stuck.

Any help would be very much appreciated. Happy New Year!

Comment: A do/while loop (or plain while) is the right choice for iteration with open end. And don't worry too much about choosing wrong. Going back and changing code and revising past design choices are just part of the process. Everybody does that.

Answer (score 0):

Use *for* loop to iterate over a collection of items or predefined set of values.
use *while* loop to check some condition and proceed for next iteration
*do-while* loop if condition check after executing some statements.
or *recursion*, if that simplifies your iteration logic(also note the performance).

Comment: So, if I use a do while loop, and put the code for a round withing the do section what should I be putting in the while section? A boolean for a question like would you like to play another round?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of different approaches to checking the letters. The first one that came to my mind was to store the letter allowance in a `Map<Character, Integer>` with the letters selected as keys and how many of each as value (no need to keep those with zero allowance).

Another approach is to have an `int[]` array matching the letters and store the allowance in there. Initialize all positions to 0 and then just increase them as letters are selected, `letterAllowance[i]++`;

Since your letter set is basically the lower case alphabet a-z you can even use the ascii value to determine the position in the array.

In both cases, you'd go through the word given by the user and count the number of letters, then checking if they match the allowance.

As mentioned, a do-while (or plain while) loop is a good choice for iteration.

**Edit - Elaboration and Code samples**

A `Map<K, V>` is a data structure which maps Keys to Values. It has the great property that lookup is in constant time, O(1). Below I will show how I thought it could be used for this application.

First though, the array solution. The premise here is that the alphabet is just a list of 26 possible values, possibly with repetitions. We can track the randomly selected characters by their position in the alphabet in an array with length 26. Each position in the array represents a letter (0 is a, 1 is b, etc.). The int value in that position shows how many of that letter the user is allowed to use.

```
final int charCount = 10;
Random r = new Random();
int[] allowedLettersArray = new int[26];
for (int i = 0; i < charCount; ++i) {
    allowedLettersArray[r.nextInt(26)]++; // 26 characters in the alphabet. Array is initialized with 0 in every position. Increase the position with 1
}
```

When the user has entered a word, we check if he picked characters that were allowed. Here I'm using a map to collect the letters in the word, counting how many of each letter was used. We then iterate over the entries in the Map and check the letter count for each letter we found (Key in the Map) against our array of allowed letters. If there were more than allowed, the word is invalid. If we don't encounter any issue, the word is valid.

```
private static boolean checkWithArray(int[] allowedLetters, String userWord) {
    // Collect user word characters to map.
    // Map key is the each letter. Map value is how many of that letter we found in the word
    Map<Integer, Long> userLetters = userWord.chars().boxed().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
    boolean wordIsValid = true;
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Long> e : userLetters.entrySet()) {
        if (e.getValue() > allowedLetters[e.getKey() - 97]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Note that we have to subtract 97 (the Ascii value of the character 'a') from the entry key to get the correct position.

Calling the method:

```
wordIsValid = checkWithArray(allowedLettersArray, userWord);
```

**Map solution**

Here is a solution with Map. In principle it works the same way as above but we use a `Map<Character, Long>` to track the allowed letters instead of an array.

Select allowed letters:

```
final int charCount = 10;
Random r = new Random();
List<Character> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < charCount; ++i) {
    list.add((char) (r.nextInt(26) + 97));
}
// Collect to Map. Count how many of each is allowed.
// Map key is each character that is allowed. Map value is how many of that character is allowed (since there may be duplicates)
Map<Character, Long> allowedLettersMap = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

Checking method:

```
private static boolean checkWithMap(Map<Character, Long> allowedLetters, String userWord) {

    // Collect word characters, same as above
    Map<Character, Long> userLetters = userWord.chars().boxed().map(i -> (char) i.intValue()).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
    boolean wordIsValid = true;
    for (Map.Entry<Character, Long> e : userLetters.entrySet()) {
        Long allowed = allowedLetters.get(e.getKey());
        if (allowed == null) {
            return false; // Word was not allowed. Contained character that was not allowed at all
        }
        if (e.getValue() > allowed) {
            return false; // Word was not allowed. Contains more of a character than is allowed
        }
    }
    return true; // No rules violations encountered, word is ok!
}
```

**Edit #2 - Code simplified and put in a class**

To put the code in a bit more context I separated it into a class. I also simplified the code to not use any Streams and only have 1 Collection, a List for the letters. It hopefully makes the code easier to read and understand.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class ArrayLetterRandomizer {
    private final int[] allowedLetters;

    public ArrayLetterRandomizer(int letterCount) {
        this.allowedLetters = new int[26];
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < letterCount; ++i) {
            allowedLetters[r.nextInt(26)]++; // 26 characters in the alphabet. Array is initialized with 0 in every position. Increase the position with 1
        }
    }

    public boolean checkWord(String word) {
        int[] wordComposition = new int[26]; // Letters a-z count
        for (char c : word.toCharArray()) {
            if (++wordComposition[c - 97] > allowedLetters[c - 97]) { // Increment letter count and check count is still within allowance
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public List<Character> getLetters() {
        List<Character> letters = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 26; ++i) {
            if (allowedLetters[i] != 0) {
                for (int j = 0; j < allowedLetters[i]; ++j) {
                    letters.add((char) (i + 97));
                }
            }
        }
        return letters;
    }
}
```

Use of the class (or interface if you want) should be easy enough to integrate into your code.

```
// Randomize 10 letters
ArrayLetterRandomizer randomizer = new ArrayLetterRandomizer(10);
// ...
if(!randomizer.checkWord(p1Answer)) {
    System.out.println("Player 1 entered an invalid word. NO PIZZA FOR YOU!");
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Map at all so would it be OK to ask more about the second option. How would I be able to know which letters match which integers if the letters are randomized? Would the int array match letters a-z and then increment if that letter is chosen in the random options?

Comment: Added code examples and very brief explanation of Map.

Comment: You are not the hero I deserve, but the one that I need. This will probably be the last thing I get to but I'll let you know how it goes tomorrow. Just to make sure I follow. If I try the array method (would be the natural first one to go to as the randomized letters are already coded into an array) and the array is done I presume I just follow the code after the //Collect to Map note? Thank you so much man. Have a great day

Comment: Hmm, not sure I follow completely. I would say that the `int[] allowedLettersArray` replaces the `letters[]` from the question. It serves the same purpose but in a different way.

Comment: Sorry, when I asked that question I was not yet in the process of doing it. I'm trying the first suggestion ATM (the stuff under Elaboration and Code samples) and am somewhat stuck at the checking method part. .I'm unsure of where to put it. Should I be creating another instantiable class for it? The Private static Boolean part is confusing me. I tried the Map solutions but ran into issues when compiling. The variable Function, Collectors and method stream() all created cannot find symbol errors. I have imported the java.util.* but my unfamiliarity with Maps could

Comment: I did leave out the imports in the code samples so you (or your IDE) would need to add those. The `private static boolean checkWithArray` is because I just ran simple test from a main method (hence static) and in the same class (so private). Don't worry about that, you can use it any way you like. Again, in the Map solution, I skipped the imports. They are usually suggested by the IDE. The last part, "Edit #2 - Code simplified and put in a class" might be easiest to start with. It's a complete class (minus imports) which you can call from your code. It should only need `java.util.*`.

Comment: Alas, for learning purposes they want us to avoid IDE's for the time being so I'm on textpad. I had imported java.util.* so that can't have been the issue. Ideally I'd like to put the private static boolean checkWithArray section into an existing instantiable class because I think then it'd be done and dusted but it's giving me errors all from the PSB line. I will try and adapt the Code Simplified and put in a class bit or maybe even just use it as an additional instantiable class but I'm very confused by the override part and the additional letterRandomizer part (unsure if its needed)

Comment: You don't need `public interface LetterRandomizer`. Skip that, remove `implements LetterRandomizer` and all `@Override` in ArrayLetterRandomizer. I updated the code in the answer and included the relevant imports.